# Оформление предложений

Tags: общие-вопросы

Есть предложение:

Одновременно с этим возобновлено производство отводов, запущены новые размеры: Ду 15, 20, 25, 32 и отвод самого крупного диаметра 630 мм.

Мне кажется, что цифровое обозначение надо как-то отделить, например:

Одновременно с этим возобновлено производство отводов, запущены новые размеры: Ду 15, 20, 25, 32 и отвод самого крупного диаметра — 630 мм.

Скобки, по-моему, будут плохо смотреться в конце предложения...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одновременно с этим возобновлено производство отводов, запущены новые размеры: Ду 15, 20, 25, 32, а также самый крупный отвод диаметром 630 мм.

Comment: Спасибо! Вот то, чего не хватало! И почему я сама не додумалась...

Answer (score 1):

Я боюсь, что такое обозначение невозможно в принципе.  Вы отрываете "ДУ" от цифр. Я бы написал: *"...запущены новые размеры: Ду 15, Ду 20, Ду 25, Ду 32..."*.

Что качается вопроса, то тире, конечно возможно, но и без него сомнений особых не возникает.

Про скобки не понял вовсе. А как бы это выглядело вообще, пусть и в варианте "плохо смотрятся"? Какую часть текста тут можно забрать в скобки - и зачем?

Comment: Я имела в виду 630 мм забрать в скобки.

Comment: У меня бы тоже не возникло сомнений, если  бы было _отвод диаметром 630 мм_, но со словами _самого крупного диаметра_ 630 мм смотрится как пояснение.

Comment: *Я имела в виду 630 мм забрать в скобки* - не, ну это совсем странно. Здесь-то это не пояснение, а основная информация.

Comment: *но со словами самого крупного диаметра 630 мм смотрится как пояснение* - у меня нет такого видения.